# Dataloaded ContentWorkspace (libraries) with no permissions and they are now hidden from all users

Tags: content, libraries, contentworkspace

I have a question about data loading ContentWorkspace (Library) records into an org. I used dataloader to load a number of library records. I set the ShouldAddCreatorMembership field to **False** so now upon creation there are no ContentWorkspaceMembership records and I cannot see or access these ContentWorkspace records at all.

How can I resolve this? Is it possible to delete these libraries (or confirm they were created) if no users have access to the library? Is there a permission I can provide to a user such that they can see all Libraries?

Any help would great as it seems there are now inaccessible orphan records that I'd like to remove.

EDIT: If I try to dataload these same ContentWorkspace records I am getting an error message - *Another library already has this name. Enter a unique name.*

Thanks

Comment: I was able to replicate this behavior in my org too. Let me check with our the concerned Salesforce product team on this aspect.

Comment: While I have an update from the team, in case you have the initial insert's success.csv file, you can fetch the Salesforce Id's and do an upsert operation setting ShouldAddCreatorMembership=true.Let me know how it goes?Thanks

Comment: @Swetha thanks for looking into this. We do not have the sucess.csv file in this case. Is there any other way to identify the IDs of the inserted records and update the ShouldAddCreatorMembership field?

Comment: I don't think much can be done without a success file. Can you log a case with Salesforce Support and share the case number here so I can own and take it forward.

Comment: I filed an investigation with the concerned team based on my org's repro and will let you know as I have more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, investigation #W-11524596 has been filed.

Summary of the investigation:

- A user should be a member of the workspace to be able to query the workspace metadata, so seems this is working as designed.
- A Library can only be accessed by a user if the user is a member of the Library. Being an Admin user does not grant the user access to any Libraries because Content does not follow the standard access model.
- Creating a Content Library in UI, adds the creator of the Library as a member of the Library and will grant user 'Library Administrator' access in the Library. But when creating the Libraries through APIs or through bulk uploads, the user has the option to set/unset the flag ShouldAddCreatorMembership. The flag should always be set to true since the flag ensures that at least one user is member of the Library. If the flag is not set, the Library will not be accessible to any user of the org.

2. If you create a Library in LEX UI, then you will notice that the user who creates the Library gets automatically added as the Library Administrator. You can check Library membership by navigating to Files -> Libraries -> library name -> Manage Members. You can reproduce similar conditions by creating a Library in LEX UI and then removing the membership of the creator.
3. In this scenario, libraries that have the flag set to false in the data loader, are created but not accessible in LEX UI.Those libraries can still be seen in the classic UI, which is not the intended behavior, but will not be fixed since Salesforce isn't investing in classic UI.

Conclusion: The only way of accessing the inserted workspace is via Classic UI and add yourself/user(s) as Library Administrator.  In case you have the initial insert's success.csv file, you can fetch the Salesforce IDs and do an upsert operation setting ShouldAddCreatorMembership=true.